# EF Code First: Retrieving a base type queries all derived type tables

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'm having an odd issue with EF 4.1 Code First where even though I have configured an entity to generate columns for its inherited properties, it still joins to the inherited type's table.

Here are my classes:

```
public class Human
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SuperHuman : Human
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Powers { get; set; }
}


public class MarvelDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Human> Humans { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SuperHuman> SuperHumans { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SuperHuman>().Map(m => m.MapInheritedProperties());
    }
}
```

Here is the resulting query:

```
    SELECT 
[Limit1].[C3] AS [C1], 
[Limit1].[C1] AS [C2], 
[Limit1].[C2] AS [C3], 
[Limit1].[C4] AS [C4]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
    [UnionAll1].[Id] AS [C1], 
    [UnionAll1].[Name] AS [C2], 
    CASE WHEN ([UnionAll1].[C2] = 1) THEN '0X' ELSE '0X0X' END AS [C3], 
    CASE WHEN ([UnionAll1].[C2] = 1) THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) ELSE [UnionAll1].[C1] END AS [C4]
    FROM  (SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C1], 
        cast(1 as bit) AS [C2]
        FROM [dbo].[Humen] AS [Extent1]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
        [Extent2].[Powers] AS [Powers], 
        cast(0 as bit) AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[SuperHumans] AS [Extent2]) AS [UnionAll1]
)  AS [Limit1]
```

I only want it to query the Humans table.

Comment: can you include the `LINQ` query and full `OnModelCreating` method body. Are you using `Table per Type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how EF behaves. If you query `Human` set it always goes over all derived tables as well because `SuperHuman` is still `Human` and because of that instances of `SuperHuman` are valid results of query for humans.