# EF4.1 - performance issue - multiple sub-classes

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-4.1

I've recently been working with EF4.1 Code First and all has been good (loving MVC), but now starting to hit major performance issues.

I have about 20 simple POCO classes derived from a *single* base class, using Table-Per-Type EF inheritance mapping:

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx

EF gives me a nice clean table hierarchy.  However, if I now load a *single* object from database, like this, it can take several seconds:

```
DerivedClass derivedObject = context.Set<DerivedClass>().Find(id);
```

I've checked lazy loading is enabled and narrowed the issue down using SQL Profiler to the SQL query created by EF to retrieve the object, which is similar to the query stucture here but ***much*** bigger:

[EF Code First: Retrieving a base type queries all derived type tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498532/ef-code-first-retrieving-a-base-type-queries-all-derived-type-tables)

As I have 20 subclasses derived from the same base class, EF is doing a SQL union and join across ***all 20 tables*** (even though I only need data from two tables - for sub and base classes), creating a result table with about 100 columns, being the total number of properties/columns in the derived + base classes.  The text lengh of the SQL query is *over 300KB* and executing the query in SQL Server Management Studio on my local machine takes about 3 seconds to retieve one row of data, which is a killer.

I've only just diagnosed this issue, so would appreciate any feedback on restructuring code to fix.  My current thoughts are:

- Flattening the object structure by using an interface instead of the base class, copying base class functionality to all sub-classes and denormalising the table hierarchy structure (denormalising not a major issue and will probably be more efficent from a db perspective, but copying base class functionality will be painful.)
- Creating sprocs for all data retrieval, including lazy loading calls (painful but possible and easy to miss a call).

Help!  Do I sacrifice OO or EF?!

If anyone knows how to simplify the SQL queries created by EF without having to restructure my class structure, that would be even better.

Comment: That is [well known issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/08/17/performance-considerations-when-using-tpt-table-per-type-inheritance-in-the-entity-framework.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is [fixed in the June 2011 EF CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx).

A possible workaround, if you can't wait for a fix, is to use TPH mapping.

Comment: Fantastic - thanks Craig - hadn't seen this CTP.  enums too - just what I want.  Any estimate on official release date for this?

Comment: @Sydney: It is very first CTP. If we look back to EFv4.1 it took far more then year between first CTP and go live licence. Hopefully this release will have shorter cycle but still I expect something between 6-12 months till go live licence.

Comment: Thanks all.  I installed the CTP and it has made an improvement to the example I gave above, but still very slow with other operations, such as:

Comment: context.Entry(derivedObject).Reload();

The article mentions that TPC mapping has issues too.  Are they as bad as TPT?  

TPH looks very "wasteful" from a db perspective to me with lots of diverse properties on derived classes.  

If TPC gets over performance issues, I'd be happy to go this way, but will still cause a lot of rewrite so need to understand impact before I restructure.