# Why does Code First Migration convert the list Human to table Humen?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

*NB No, this is **not** a typo. It appears that CF will actually change the name. In fact, I even [asked about it](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/80273/can-plural-of-human-ever-be-humen) on English Stack Exchange, to be sure that it's not an unexpected conjugation.*

My context is as follows (including the signature of the classes).

```
public class Model : DbContext
{
  public Model() : base("name=Model") { }
  public virtual DbSet<Human> Humans { get; set; }
  public virtual DbSet<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}
public class Human { ... }
public class Activity { ... }
```

Now, when I run *Add-Migration Init*, to my biggest surprise I get this in *Up()* and *Down()*.

```
public override void Up() {
  CreateTable("dbo.Activities", c => ... )
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
  CreateTable("dbo.Humen", c => ... )
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
}
public override void Down() {
  DropTable("dbo.Humen");
  DropTable("dbo.Activities");
}
```

What on Earth is that about? I've been working with EF for years and never seen anything like this. I've searched the whole solution for *Humen* and the only occurrences are in the migration file.

Googling gave nothing, not even a small confirmation of such thing **but** if you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6498532/1675891), I see that user's got the *Humen* table too. And check the conversation - they talk about *Human(s)* without actually realizing that the table name's spelled differently!

Now, am I going insane or what the duck is that?! (Typo intended.)

Comment: Is this not just faulty pluralisation?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The thought stroke me too. Then, if it's not the generic adding an "s" to everything, then it's some kind of elaborate ad-hoc fix. And if that's the case, who'd pluralize it that way? Having said that, weirder things have happened... How can we verify it?

Comment: IIRC, the pluralization methods can be called directly nowadays, so you could use that to check.

Comment: This might interest you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498532/ef-code-first-retrieving-a-base-type-queries-all-derived-type-tables checkout the `Humens` on that one

Comment: @hvd I'm not following... I haven't invoked any pluralizations explicitly myself. Not entirely sure how to check the thing you mentioned. Could you provide more info, please?

Comment: @AydinAdn Mmkey... Any special reason why you give me a link to that post? If you read my question, I'm referring to that very post myself. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: ooo... what a screw up... I had googled   `public virtual DbSet<Human> Humans { get; set; }` without visiting the link you provided... sorry about that... You probably already know this but if you want to stop it, you could just add the `TableAnnotation` providing the name of the table you wish to use. I know that isn't an answer to your question regarding why it names it like that, but I wouldn't worry about it since its so easy to change

Comment: @KonradViltersten I meant calling `EnglishPluralizationService.Pluralize("Human")`. If it gives `"Humen"` rather than `"Humans"`, there's the problem. Given that you already accepted to explicitly specify the table name though, there may not be much point in checking now.

Comment: @hvd Oh, cool. I've never even heard of it. I assumed that the pluralization was done by a dummy suffixing of "s" for all words and languages. Not sure how to verify it in the class, though. Is there a source code for it available anywhere? I only find DLL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To override it, you could add a `TableAnnotation` to your entity, you'll need to run add-migration again, making sure that you're overwriting the previous version...

```
[Table("Human")]
public class Human { ... }
```

Two other alternate methods...

One involves going directly into the Migration that was generated and modifying the values of the methods `Up()` and `Down()`...

And last but not least... The `ÈntityTypeConfiguration`s which is used in your `DbContext`, simply override a protected method called `OnModelCreating` in your DbContext, and implement this example...

```
// HumanConfiguration.cs
public class HumanConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Human>
{
    public HumanConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("Human");
    }
}

// YourDbContext.cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new HumanConfiguration());
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```